# Proof regarding the rank of a matrix and the determinant of its sub matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Define Z as an m×n matrix. Show that Z has rank m if and only
if the determinant of some m × m sub-matrix of Z, which is obtained by
deleting the n − m columns of Z, is nonzero.

I have managed to show the forward direction for this proof. I'm stuck in showing the reverse however (Starting with the submatrix and the determinant of the submatrix being non-zero). I know that it has m linear independent columns, thus rank = m. How can I always know that adding the n-m columns back keeps the rank = m. Must I just assume they're linearly dependent from the other m columns? Thank you.

Comment: Well, can it decrease the rank? Can it increase the rank?

Comment: I'm sure it could increase the rank, but that wouldn't be supporting my proof.

Comment: Increase the rank beyond $m$ (the number of rows of the matrix)? That would be quite a surprise.

Comment: Sorry why is that not possible, isn't linear independency based upon columns and not rows. Sorry I'm very new to algebra like this. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh, you don't know "row rank = column rank" yet. Do you know that more than $m$ vectors in an $m$-dimensional space must always be linearly dependent?

Comment: Yes and I do know about ranks but haven't seen row rank = column rank. Does this link to the reason that the rank cannot increase?

Comment: Yes. But if you know that the rank is the maximum # of linearly independent column, then it should be enough to see why $m+1$ columns cannot be linearly independent.

Comment: I can't quite see it, could you give me a brief explanation if possible. Because how can you assure m+1 columns aren't linearly independent also.  Thank you :)

Comment: Well, $m+1$ columns are $m+1$ vectors in an $m$-dimensional space. Now recall what you know about extending linearly independent tuples of vectors to bases.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, coming back to his, what am I meant to know about extending linearly independent tuples of vectors to bases. I haven't heard about that. Thank you